# Class not registered Exception on initializing PackAndGoLib.PackAndGoComponent

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am unable to use **CreatePackAndGo** feature on Forge as I am getting the following Exception

'Exception Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F2D4F4E5-EEA1-46FF-A83B-A270C92DAE4B} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).' on the line mentioned below.

`Dim oPacknGoComp As New PackAndGoLib.PackAndGoComponent`

I have also tried by changing the project **Target CPU to x86 and x64** but still problem exists. Currently referencing **Autodesk.PackAndGo.Interop** as **Embed Interop Types = True**.

This PackAndGo function is working fine when running on Local Machine with Inventor 2020 in the same project.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Why do you need it on DA? Its main purpose is to gather all the necessary files together from your local system where they might be spread around. But in case of DA, all your files need to be together already (usually zipped up) in order to use them

Comment: Yes right , in order to do the minimal changes in my existing application. I was aiming to do that in DA, which is not required(can be done on the Local Machine, if required). Thanks!